# Expectation value of $\theta$ for the bivariate normal distribution in polar coordinates {$r$,$\theta$}

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, polar-coordinates

Consider the bivariate normal distribution with standard deviation $\sigma$ and mean displaced to a point $x_0$ along the $x$-axis. In polar coordinates, the pdf is expressed as:

$$\rho(r,\theta)=\frac{r}{2\pi\sigma^2}\exp\left[-\frac{(r\cos{\theta}-x_0)^2+(r\sin{\theta})^2}{2\sigma^2}\right]$$

The expectation value for $\theta$ is then:

$$\overline{\theta}=\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^\infty dr\ \theta\ \rho(r,\theta) $$

I am not aware of an analytical result to the above integral, but numerical calculation for $x_0\gt0$ and $\sigma\ll x_0$ gives $\overline{\theta}=\pi$. At first glance, this result seems counterintuitive, because it indicates that the mean of the pdf lies somewhere at $x_0 \lt 0$. On the other hand, the region over which $\rho(r,\theta)$ is most pronounced straddles the discontinuity between $\theta\sim 0$ and $\theta\sim 2\pi$ in equal measure, and in this respect $\overline{\theta}$ would seem to give an average of these two values, which is just $\pi$.

The "intuitive" result $\overline{\theta}=0$ can be obtained by simply redefining the limits of integration over $\theta$ to be from $-\pi$ to $\pi$, effectively rotating the $\theta$ discontinuity/cut angle to the $-x$-axis. That's fine for this case, but what happens when one has to deal with a normal distribution displaced to any arbitrary point in the $(r,\theta)$-plane? Or even worse, when the origin is located within a few $\sigma$ of the centroid of the pdf? Is there a generic way to handle this, or does one have to tailor the integral for each case in turn?

Comment: Simulations with R indicate that $\overline{\theta}$ is around $0$ not $\pi$

Comment: Displacment by an arbitrary $(r_0, \theta_0)$ doesn't seem hard: just rotate until you end up in the original case where you are displacing along the $x$-coordinate.

Comment: @athalhaids I can't comment on your simulation result, as I don't know what's involved in the simulation. Regarding your second comment: yes, you can rotate the coordinates on a case-by-case basis. I don't think that would handle those cases where the centroid of the pdf is near to the origin, but I'm sure shifting the origin would handle those cases in a similar way.

Comment: In any event, those methods imply a foreknowledge of the centroid of the pdf, which is somewhat more computationally expensive to obtain than applying a generic formula for the expectation value. The question I am asking is whether such a formula exists.